# Apple Watch OS2 beta 3 - App stuck spinning on physical watch

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-watch, xcode7-beta3

We're developing an app for Android Wear and Apple watches. We can't get our Apple watch to actually run our app, it just shows a spinner when opened up. Note the app runs fine in the simulator.

I've tried rebooting, uninstalling, resetting, cleaning the project, in pretty much every combination you could think of.

Does anybody know a workaround to get the app running on the watch at all? I found this solution on the apple dev forums:

> Product -> Archive  [You may have some code signing issues to figure
>   out here--especially if you have multiple people who sign the builds
>   for your organization.]
>
> Export... -> for Ad Hoc Distribution
>
> Uninstall the app from your iPhone.
>
> Drop the ipa file onto iTunes.
>
> Select your iPhone in iTunes, go to the Apps tab, and find the app you
>   just dropped in.
>
> Click install.
>
> Click apply.
>
> Make sure that "Show App on Apple Watch" is selected in the Apple
>   Watch app, and wait for it to install.

However, my issue there is I can't seem to find the Ad-Hoc Distribution option after my archive. Do I need to have something set up for this?

Comment: Maybe the problem is not the OS but a class used in the project. Some libraries run on the simulator but don't work on iOS/Watch OS. I'd check for incompatible libraries!

Comment: I originally thought this as well, but I'm only using the default frameworks, and I only currently have a label showing on the watch app for testing purposes. I have the UIKit, Foundation, and Watchkit frameworks installed for my project